# Why .remove() doesn't remove the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/uz6y3L2y/2/) is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
          top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
          left     = self.position().left;
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
      $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", left: left + "px"}).fadeIn(200);   
    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    if(this.iid){
      clearTimeout(this.iid)
      remove($('.tag_info'));
    }
  });
});
```

As you see in the fiddle I've provided, when your mouse leaves the tag, that black box still exists. Why? And how can I remove it?

Comment: Try `$('.tag_info').remove()`

Comment: why you didn't do that with `:hover`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below code instead.

```
$('.tag_info').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
remove($('.tag_info'));
```

should be

```
$('.tag_info').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
          top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
          left     = self.position().left;
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
      $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", left: left + "px"}).fadeIn(200);   
    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
  $('.tag_info').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
    body{
      padding: 20px;
    }

    a {
        color: #3e6d8e !important;
        background-color: #E1ECF4;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    .tag_info{
      position: absolute;
      width: 130px;
      height: 100px;
      display:none;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a>tag1</a>
    <a>tag2</a>
```

```
check the code `https://jsfiddle.net/uz6y3L2y/3/` may help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery selector define in first.

```
$('.tag_info').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery funciton [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) in wrong way, that's why it does not removing the element which has class `.tag_info`. Please use it as per [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
remove($('.tag_info')); // Not Correct
```

You need to use it like this

```
$('.tag_info').remove();
```